# How to download the google maven libs?

Tags: android, maven

I can see the libs here: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html

But I don't know how to download this. I don't know how the links are doing.

I want to download with the `curl` command or even in the browser with the full link.

I know that the link should be like:

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraint-layout/constraint-layout/2.0.0-beta4/constraint-layout-2.0.0-beta4.jar
```

Comment: This is a Maven repository. You usually use it from Maven or Gradle to build applications. No need to download the artifacts first.

Comment: @JFMeier I know, but I need download the files to add in my android app that doesn't use Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraintlayout/constraintlayout/2.0.0-beta4/constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta4.aar

So, to download I saw in the https://maven.google.com/web/index.html:

- androidx.constraintlayout

  - constraintlayout
  - 2.0.0-beta4

And I translated to:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraintlayout/constraintlayout/2.0.0-beta4/

And you need know what the file you want, in my case I need one `.aar` file:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraintlayout/constraintlayout/2.0.0-beta4/constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta4.aar